# Material-UI Icon element cropping FontAwesome icon

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, font-awesome

I'm using Material-UI Icon element with Font Awesome icons, but when I use a non-square icon, the icon is cropped. This is how Material-UI suggest to use:

`<Icon className="fa fa-address-card />`

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yhlk4v?file=index.js

Element CSS:

```
width: 1em;
height: 1em;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 1.5rem;
flex-shrink: 0;
-moz-user-select: none;
```

I have tried to limit icon width (`max-width`), but this doesn't worked.
What I want is: the icon must NOT overpass Material-UI icon default width (1rem), so I need to manipulate icon height, but FA icons size are controlled by `font-size`, and just change it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because both libraries styles override each other, So you have to override the one with other like below

Solution 1:(font-awesome)

```
.fa {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

OR

Solution 2:(Material-UI )

```
.MuiIcon-root {
    width: auto;
}
```

Or without changing width try this

```
.fa:before {
  font-size: smaller !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I just edited my question. I can't change icon width.

Comment: @AlexandreAragão Did you tried first solution with !important `.fa {
    display: inline-table !important ;
}`

Comment: Yep, but like I said, this change icon default WIDTH and I need to keep width but change height (font-size)

Comment: @AlexandreAragão Update my answer please check without changing width

Answer (score 0):

[your container width for icon is smaller than that of icon, i tried 30x24 and got full icone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTSBE.png)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I think you can post this answer as a comment.

Comment: @KomalShrestha thank you, I just edited my question. I can't change icon width.